# error ocuuring ::: failed to install tomcat 7 service

Tags: windows-xp, tomcat, java

While I'm trying to install Tomcat(apache-tomcat-7.0.23.exe) on my system (Windows XP SP3), which is in company's network, it is showing me the following error:

> failed to install tomcat 7 service Check your setting and permission Ignore and continue anyway

I have jdk 7 installed on my computer and giving its jre path while installing tomcat....
I have tried to change the port number 8080 to another port (9090) also while installing but it didnt work !!!!!!

Could you please tell me what the problem is and a possible solution?

Comment: perhaps not enough privileges in your machine to install new stuff. Try using tomcat without installing it, you can actually run it without performing installation, just running the .bat files in /bin folder.

Comment: also which OS? Some OS require superuser rights for the programs to listen to ports under 1024

Comment: currently trying to install it on win xp

Comment: Not nearly enough information given - update the original question with OS, whether you are a local admin (probably not), method of installation (I'm assuming the Windows-specific MSI), ...

Comment: i have updated the question with the required details now can u figure out the porblem with that or should i need to give any other information also??

Answer (score 1):

I was able to start Tomcat7 service by following approach

Set environment variable
 *CATALINA_HOME to the tomcat directory if not set.*

- Press Win key then type `cmd` in search field.
- Press `Ctrl+Shift` then click **CMD**.(This will open command prompt in Admin mode)
- `cd  to/your/tomcat/folder`
- fire command `service.bat install`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this issue because tomcat with same 'Tomcat Window Service Name' is already installed or running on your machine.

So, Mention different 'Tomcat Window Service Name' while installing it on window, where you mention admin credentials and port etc.

Answer (score 0):

Same error due to an old Tomcat not properly uninstalled, the steps I did:

1. Install Tomcat with ignore warning
2. Uninstall Tomcat from windows -> uninstall program
3. Go to regedit -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> remove Apache Software Foundation
4. Restart computer (I don’t know if this is useful but its always a good thing)

Now I can install Tomcat fine

Answer (score -1):

I was also taking this warning, and ı figure it out that I deleted installed tomcat folder on system without uninstall it. so to fix it I checked it in "regedit" and it is fix it.
to do this first write "regedit" to start and than system registiration window will be shown, then go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", then "software", than delete the file whichs likes "Apache...." file.